# NSKeyedUnarchiver Always Returns nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, nskeyedunarchiver

I am attempting to store data in between app closures and power cycles using NSKeyedArchiver. The root object I am trying to store is a NSMutableArray, but within this there are collections of Foundation and Custom objects (all of which conform to NSCoding).

The file save code is as follows

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sessionDataSaveFile",documentsDirectory];
    
NSMutableData *pData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    
NSKeyedArchiver *archiver = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initRequiringSecureCoding:NO];
[archiver encodeObject:self.sessionData];
[archiver finishEncoding];
[pData appendData:[archiver encodedData]];
[pData writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:YES];
```

The file saves fine and no exceptions are thrown. On launching the app again, this file is recovered using the following code.

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sessionDataSaveFile", documentsDirectory];

NSData *pData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
NSError *error = nil;
NSKeyedUnarchiver *unArchiver = [[NSKeyedUnarchiver alloc] initForReadingFromData:pData error:&error];
self.sessionData = [unArchiver decodeObject];
[unArchiver finishDecoding];
```

At this point, sessionData is always nil, however pData is several thousand bytes long, thus I know the problem is in the decoding method. I have tried `[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCoder]` and just about every variation of the NSKeyedUnarchiver methods, but still no use. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Why do you use `NSKeyedArchiver` if you already have `NSData`?

Comment: How do you mean? Am I able to write the NSData directly to a file without using NSKeyedArchiver to convert from NSMutableArray?

Comment: I don't see why you use `NSKeyedArchiver`  & `NSKeyedUnarchiver`. I would do: `[self.sessionData writeToFile:fullFileName atomically:YES]` & `self.sessionData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];`.

Comment: Sorry, should have clarified - self.sessionData is NSMutableArray. I've just tried the following.

To Write:
`NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *fullFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/sessionDataSaveFile",documentsDirectory];`
To read
`self.sessionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:fullFileName];
    if(self.sessionData == nil){
        self.sessionData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }`
No luck!

Comment: `[NSKeyedarchived archivedDataWithRootObject:self.sessionData requiringSecureCoding:YES error:&error];` then? Also, aren't `error` param nil after calls?

Answer (score 0):

Solved!

Switched to using `NSFileManager` and doing a simple swap between array and data to store at a particular path.